# facing issues in primeNG while migrating angular application

Tags: html, angular, migration, primeng

[image]

While migrating my project from angular version 7 to 13, I am facing issues in the primeNG.

I have mentioned the isuues in which i am facing, and also mentioned my package.json file.

[image]

I changes the themes of primeNG, changes the primeNG versions , checked whether is there any issues in module import.

Comment: Please don't add code as images.

Answer (score 0):

As of the **PrimeNG V15** official documentation:

> Responsive
> Dialog width can be adjusted per screen size with the
> breakpoints option. In example below, default width is set to 50vw and
> below 961px, width would be 75vw and finally below 641px width becomes
> 100%. The value of breakpoints should be an object literal whose keys
> are the maximum screen sizes and values are the widths per screen.

1. First, you should import the DialogModule to your module
2. These are the new responsive properties :
   Style to assign the default layout and breakpoints to optimize it for responsive

```
<p-dialog [(visible)]="display" [breakpoints]="{'960px': '75vw', '640px': '100vw'}" [style]="{width: '50vw'}">
    Content
</p-dialog>
```

**Working Stackblitz example :**

https://primeng-dialog-demo-jgavrr.stackblitz.io